# Android - Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am getting this error when i try to build my game for android. But it successfully built to webplayer. i checked everything is right,
and one think recently i upgrade my unity to 4.5.1

Error details are:

```
Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.
D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "D:/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030/sdk/platforms/android-18\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_

stderr[
AndroidManifest.xml:9: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version').
]
stdout[
Configurations:
 (default)
 hdpi
 ldpi
 xhdpi
 xxhdpi

Files:
  drawable\app_icon.png
    Src: () res\drawable\app_icon.png
    Src: (hdpi) res\drawable-hdpi\app_icon.png
    Src: (ldpi) res\drawable-ldpi\app_icon.png
    Src: (xhdpi) res\drawable-xhdpi\app_icon.png
    Src: (xxhdpi) res\drawable-xxhdpi\app_icon.png
  values\strings.xml
    Src: () res\values\strings.xml
  AndroidManifest.xml
    Src: () AndroidManifest.xml

Resource Dirs:
  Type drawable
    drawable\app_icon.png
      Src: () res\drawable\app_icon.png
      Src: (hdpi) res\drawable-hdpi\app_icon.png
      Src: (ldpi) res\drawable-ldpi\app_icon.png
      Src: (xhdpi) res\drawable-xhdpi\app_icon.png
      Src: (xxhdpi) res\drawable-xxhdpi\app_icon.png
  Type values
    values\strings.xml
      Src: () res\values\strings.xml
Including resources from package: D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\platforms\android-18\android.jar
applyFileOverlay for drawable
applyFileOverlay for layout
applyFileOverlay for anim
applyFileOverlay for animator
applyFileOverlay for interpolator
applyFileOverlay for transition
applyFileOverlay for xml
applyFileOverlay for raw
applyFileOverlay for color
applyFileOverlay for menu
applyFileOverlay for mipmap
Processing image: res\drawable-hdpi\app_icon.png
Processing image: res\drawable\app_icon.png
    (processed image res\drawable\app_icon.png: 97% size of source)
Processing image: res\drawable-ldpi\app_icon.png
    (processed image res\drawable-ldpi\app_icon.png: 98% size of source)
Processing image: res\drawable-xhdpi\app_icon.png
    (processed image res\drawable-hdpi\app_icon.png: 98% size of source)
Processing image: res\drawable-xxhdpi\app_icon.png
    (processed image res\drawable-xhdpi\app_icon.png: 98% size of source)
    (processed image res\drawable-xxhdpi\app_icon.png: 98% size of source)
    (new resource id app_icon from drawable\app_icon.png #generated)
    (new resource id app_icon from hdpi\drawable\app_icon.png #generated)
    (new resource id app_icon from ldpi\drawable\app_icon.png #generated)
    (new resource id app_icon from xhdpi\drawable\app_icon.png #generated)
    (new resource id app_icon from xxhdpi\drawable\app_icon.png #generated)
]
```

Comment: Can you give more information, are you using any plugins for Android?

Comment: @nexx no i am not using any plugin

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I deleted the 24.0.0 build tools folder from Android\sdk\build-tools and it's working !

Comment: PERFECT. I found out that this issue fixed my issue. For some reason there is something in the 24.0.0 Build tools that just doesn't work. Remove this package and install 23.0.3 and it should build and compile perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the google_play_service_lib folder from the androidsdk\extra\google folder in plugins\android in order to make it work properly.

You can find it in android-sdk-windows\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject. There you will find google_play_service_lib. You copy it in plugins/android in unity

Credit to Ouss.

note: if it's already in there, then chances are you've updated the android sdk, so you need the new lib folder. Close out of unity > delete the google play services lib folder > go to you sdk folder listed above > copy the lib folder in the address above > go back to your android plugins folder in your unity app > paste it in there > reopen unity and allow the scripts to compile > build.

Answer (score 2):

There is a new problem out there. In case you installed the Android preview SDK 24.0.0 (if you have such a folder inside the build tools folder) then unity does not build  / repackage properly.

I see this issue:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.
C:\android-sdk\build-tools\24.0.0-preview\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "C:/android-sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages android.support.v7.appcompat:com.everyplay.Everyplay:com.google.example.games.mainlibproj:com.google.android.gms.base:com.google.android.gms:com.google.android.gms.drive:com.google.android.gms.games:com.google.android.gms.nearby:com.google.android.gms.plus:android.support.v4 -S "C:\Workspace\Spacegame\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.1.1\res" -S "C:\Workspace\Spacegame\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\everyplay\res" -S "C:\Workspace\Spacegame\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-8.4.0\res" -S "C:\Workspace\Spacegame\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-basement-8.4.0\res" -S "C:\Workspace\Spacegame\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-drive-8.4.0\res" -S "C:\Workspace\Spacegame\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-games-8.4.0\res" -S "C:\Workspace\Spacegame\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-nearby-8.4.0\res" -S "C:\Workspace\Spacegame\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-plus-8.4.0\res" -S "C:\Workspace\Spacegame\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-v4-23.1.1\res"

stderr[

]
stdout[
Configurations:
 (default)

Files:
  AndroidManifest.xml
    Src: () AndroidManifest.xml

Resource Dirs:
Including resources from package: C:\android-sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar
applyFileOverlay for drawable
trying overlaySet Key=ic_plusone_medium_off_client.png
trying overlaySet Key=ic_plusone_small_off_client.png
trying overlaySet Key=ic_plusone_standard_off_client.png
trying overlaySet Key=ic_plusone_tall_off_client.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_full_open_on_phone.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_disabled.9.png
```

The only working solution I found is to uninstall the 24.0.0 build tools folder - means simply delete it and restart Unity. Seems that Unity has issues with the new Android 24 build tools.

Edit: you'll find the build tools folder inside your Android SDK Folder

Answer (score 1):

What i did and it worked.

i had only jre not jdk. First i download jdk from oracle site.
set up environments path:

JAVA_HOME
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin

but error exist again.

========================================

Then i got this guide: 
try this and tell if it works.

copy zipalign.exe file from   >    D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W

or where ever you have it and then Past to > D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools

[Unity3diy forums](http://unity3diy.blogspot.com/p/forums.html)

And everything works perfect :)

Comment: didn't work for v22 or v23 - please specify which version you're using