# Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

```
Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package
resources. See the Console for details.
D:\Programming\IDE\adt\sdk\build-tools\21.0.0\aapt.exe package
--auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" ...
```

I  really need some help. I am about to release the 2nd alpha version of my app to test the play services. but this error keeps on popping? do you know How can I get rid of this. tried removing androidmanifest like other said. reimporting but it is still there?

Comment: Do you have the JDK installed? Similar error message here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348615/android-error-building-player-commandinvokationfailure-failed-to-re-package

Comment: yup. but its jdk 7. should i use 8?

Comment: oh. nvm. a guy name Terrell Stephen got it. https://plus.google.com/115465454488748153540/posts/aBnJLvujuUq

Answer (score 2):

This is a crash in aapt on Windows: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77629
FIxed in 21.0.2, please install this version of build-tools and uninstall 21.0.0 and 21.0.1.

Comment: However, it didn't work for me since i just edited the manifest by arranging spacing only and i didn't altered any slight code.

Comment: Well, if you have something wrong with your manifest, you will be able to see the output of AAPT and understand what's wrong. With build-tools 21.0.0 and 21.0.1, AAPT just crashed leaving no output.

Comment: My latest build tool is 23. My error is pointed at Android 4.4W since after when I installed a unity package for Google Ads for both Android and iOS. I'm focusing on Android. It worked the first time and a couple of times, maybe 3 times, on testing if the fullscreen ad mode is picking up or something. When I re-run it, I got the build failure error due to repackaging.

Here's where I got the tutorials and the links to the latest Unity package from Git: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NR1xOMxLm04

Comment: Whoops! Version 23 is from Android SDK Tools. My current Build Tool is 20 and I decided to delete it an install the latest one. I'll checking for errors once I've installed it.

Comment: Built-tool ver 21.1.1 is installed. I re-run it with Google Ads via Unity but nothing happened. Got build failure. (*Failed to repackage resources.*)

Comment: Checking on consoles and found missing resources at manifest: *[
AndroidManifest.xml:9: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version').] stdout[Configurations: (default) Files: drawable\app_icon.png*

Comment: Solved by adding the *Google play service* folder and generate R for ID named "Integer" by importing existing code via Eclipse. (You need it though.) Calibrate target SDK. Next, I suddenly realize there is an error at *manifest* on values for *configChanges* since I broke up into several lines. I decided not to back where it is.

Answer (score 0):

> Version 21+ of the Android SDK Build-tools does not seem to work.
> Using the SDK Manager, downgrade to Version 20 and that should fix
> your issue.
>
> -- Thanks to  [Terrell Stephen](https://plus.google.com/110185852703918521653/posts)

[Link](https://plus.google.com/110185852703918521653/posts)

Answer (score 0):

Copy google-play-services_lib folder to Plugins/Android, so you don't have to hard code Google Play Service's value. https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-plugins/issues/11

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue but resolved it by moving SDK folder to C drive (I mean same installation **drive (not folder)** as unity). If you have space issues in your OS drive then just download new SDK from google and place it on C drive.