# Failed to recompile android resource file

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, kudan

I'm trying to build "My First App" with that [tutorial](https://wiki.kudan.eu/My_First_Augmented_Reality_App_(1.1.3_Stable)) also i tried to build with [another tutorial for version 1.2](https://wiki.kudan.eu/My_First_Augmented_Reality_App_(1.2)) for android, but every time i get the same error "Failed to recompile android resource files". In the console i see

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\platforms\android-24\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages eu.kudan.androidar -S "C:\Users\User\Documents\MyFirstKudanApp\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\KudanPlugin\res"

stderr[

]
stdout[

]
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.Exec (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.String[] progress_strings, Single progress_value, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.CompileResources (System.String stagingArea, System.String packageName, UnityEditor.Android.AndroidLibraries androidLibraries)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcessInternal (System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

and

```
Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\platforms\android-24\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages eu.kudan.androidar -S "C:\Users\User\Documents\MyFirstKudanApp\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\KudanPlugin\res"

stderr[

]
stdout[

]
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be due to a bug from 24.0.0 build tools that you are using. Try deleting the 24.0.0 build tools folder from your SDK manager and restart Unity. Here's a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348615/android-error-building-player-commandinvokationfailure-failed-to-re-package) that has similar problems.

Comment: You was right! Now it's working! i just delete android-24 folder from C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms

Comment: I've tried anything plus any of the solutions on this page. It just doesn't work cause now they released v. 25 and JDK 1.9. I'm sick of this disrespectful incompatibility issues that we have to solve by trial and error until the next update messes it up again and brings us back to square one. And they keep on releasing updates without looking into the issues. Dislike me, do whatever you want...

Answer (score 4):

Only because what I did worked for me, I'm going to throw this up there for anyone who may run into this issue. I was trying to build for Nougat, and I didn't even have the `24` build tools in my Android SDK folder.

I have JDK 1.7.0_79 installed as well as JSD 1.8.0_101. It looks like Unity tried to use the 1.7 version. I switched to use 1.8 in **Unity -> Preferences -> External Tools -> JDK** and this ended up compiling everything for me.

Comment: This was the solution for me. I was trying to get the Google Daydream demo project running in Unity 5.6.

Comment: Before I had to downgrade to sdk tools 25.2.3. Afterwards, this answer works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message at the first time I used Unity.
I tried download the latest Android SDK and latest build tool, but no use.
Changing the JDK version solved the problem.
[image]