# CommandInvokationFailure when attempting to build APK

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk

I get `CommandInvokationFailure` error when attempting to build APK. I deleted my Android SDK Build Tool and then forced to update it though Unity but that didn't change anything. **When I build with a new empty project, I don't get the error.** What should I do?

I've also re-downloaded the SDK from [here](http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows.zip) and updated path in Unity.

I have the following installed:

- Google Play Services
- I think I installed Android Support Library - I'm not sure.
- Local Maven repository for Support Libraries (Also known as Android Support - Repository)
- Google Repository
- Android 6.0 (API 23) (this does not affect the min SDK version).

Comment: Can you clean the project?

Comment: try deleting 24.0.0 build tools folder from Android\sdk\build-tools (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348615/android-error-building-player-commandinvokationfailure-failed-to-re-package)

Comment: @quidproquo I already did that. Read my post again.

Comment: @Dake check to see if you've included the plugin twice?

Comment: Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: Can you post the error description?  `CommandInvokationFailure` is a type, it should put some sort of explanation in your console when you click on the error.  I'm guessing this has to do with AndroidManifest files having different MinimumApi levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a file called `version.xml` in the folder `google-play-services_lib/res/values` of Google Play Services.

You need to copy this into the folder `Assets/Plugins/Android/res/values/` of your Unity project.

Comment: I don't have such files.

Comment: What was your solution? Please post it so that others with the-same problem will find the right solution.