# Cant find 'google-play-services_lib' anywhere

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services, fyber

Right now I'm trying to get Fyber working in my Unity game on Android.

and have run into issues at [the following step..](http://developer.fyber.com/content/current/unity/integration/building-your-app/#android)

"Keep in mind that adding the line above to your manifest will require you to add Google Play Services lib to your project. You copy the google-play-services_lib project from your android sdk path (usually under Android/sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib) to your Unity project under Plugins\Android"

I dont even know if Im looking for a file or a folder but I cant find any file or folder named
"google-play-services_lib" in my Android sdk or in the [last distributed lib project from google repository](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_play_services_8487000_r29.ziphttp://) they also recommend downloading if your having issues.

Heres the full error I'm getting when I try to build at the moment

```
    CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.
    C:\Users\Blar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.3\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "C:/Users/Blar/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\platforms\android-24\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_

    stderr[
    AndroidManifest.xml:17: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version').

    ]
    stdout[
    Configurations:
     (default)
     v14
     v21
     xhdpi-v4

    Files:
      drawable\app_banner.png
        Src: (xhdpi-v4) res\drawable-xhdpi\app_banner.png
      drawable\app_icon.png
        Src: () res\drawable\app_icon.png
      values\strings.xml
        Src: () res\values\strings.xml
      values\styles.xml
        Src: () res\values\styles.xml
        Src: (v14) res\values-v14\styles.xml
        Src: (v21) res\values-v21\styles.xml
      AndroidManifest.xml
        Src: () AndroidManifest.xml

    Resource Dirs:
      Type drawable
        drawable\app_banner.png
          Src: (xhdpi-v4) res\drawable-xhdpi\app_banner.png
        drawable\app_icon.png
          Src: () res\drawable\app_icon.png
      Type values
        values\strings.xml
          Src: () res\values\strings.xml
        values\styles.xml
          Src: () res\values\styles.xml
          Src: (v14) res\values-v14\styles.xml
          Src: (v21) res\values-v21\styles.xml
    Including resources from package: C:\Users\Blar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-24\android.jar
    applyFileOverlay for drawable
    applyFileOverlay for layout
    applyFileOverlay for anim
    applyFileOverlay for animator
    applyFileOverlay for interpolator
    applyFileOverlay for transition
    applyFileOverlay for xml
    applyFileOverlay for raw
    applyFileOverlay for color
    applyFileOverlay for menu
    applyFileOverlay for mipmap
    Processing image: res\drawable\app_icon.png
    Processing image: res\drawable-xhdpi\app_banner.png
        (processed image res\drawable\app_icon.png: 90% size of source)
        (processed image res\drawable-xhdpi\app_banner.png: 93% size of source)
        (new resource id app_banner from xhdpi-v4\drawable\app_banner.png #generated)
        (new resource id app_icon from drawable\app_icon.png #generated)
    ]
    UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
    UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.TasksCommon.Exec (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.String errorMsg, Int32 retiresOnFailure)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a folder called 'google-play-services_lib' in the last distributed lib project from google repository you also recommend downloading, and copied it into Plugins\Android.

But it did not fix my issue. I am still getting the same error when I try to build

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [forum](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/760989/failed-to-re-package-resources-2.html), maybe you have an `AndroidManifest.xml` file (probably under Plugins/Android or a plugin in a subfolder of this folder) that tries to access a resource by name (`google_play_services_version`), but this value is never defined anywhere. Usually, this value is added via some method such as adding it to the `AndroidManifest.xml` or to an `xml` under res/values.

To fix this error, you have to copy the `version.xml` file from **android-sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/res/values/** into **Assets/Plugins/Android/res/values/** of your Unity project's folder.

You can also check this related thread: [Android - Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348615/android-error-building-player-commandinvokationfailure-failed-to-re-package) which suggested to delete the 24.0.0 build tools folder from Android\sdk\build-tools.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to install Adjust SDK to our Unity project.

'google-play-services_lib' was mentioned in Adjust SDK pdf document as "if you want to use Google Services, you need to copy google-play-services_lib under the following folder".

My colleague said it is a folder that comes up when you download some other Google SDK like Firebase SDK.

Since we did not use something like that, I have ignored this part of the tutorial.